# Can consolekit sefely be removed, when running headless (no GUI)?

Tags: raspbian, gui, headless, terminal, logfiles

Lately I am getting a lot of the following messages in my `/var/log/syslog`:

```
Aug 26 07:48:20 raspberrypi console-kit-daemon[2376]: GLib-CRITICAL: Source ID 42 was not found when attempting to remove it
Aug 26 07:49:47 raspberrypi console-kit-daemon[2376]: GLib-CRITICAL: Source ID 14 was not found when attempting to remove it
Aug 26 07:49:47 raspberrypi console-kit-daemon[2376]: GLib-CRITICAL: Source ID 14 was not found when attempting to remove it
Aug 26 08:14:40 raspberrypi console-kit-daemon[2376]: GLib-CRITICAL: Source ID 73 was not found when attempting to remove it
Aug 26 08:14:40 raspberrypi console-kit-daemon[2376]: GLib-CRITICAL: Source ID 73 was not found when attempting to remove it
```

A quick web-search showed I am [not the only one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/571395/glib-critical-console-kit-daemon) many propose to simply [remove the `console-kit`](https://appbead.com/blog/fix-errors-reported-in-syslog-for-debian-8-jessie.html) when it regards a headless server as it should only be necessary for Graphical logins (that I personally do not require nor have).

So I am on the brink to `apt-get purge consolekit`. But when I read its [official documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/ConsoleKit/doc/ConsoleKit.html) it seems to have a wider (login) application than solely required for GUI logins:

> a framework for keeping track of the various users, sessions, and
>   seats present on a system. It provides a mechanism for software to
>   react to changes of any of these items or of any of the metadata
>   associated with them.

Hence my question:

- Can consolekit *[indeed](https://serverfault.com/questions/160612/console-kit-daemon-can-it-be-stopped)* safely be removed, when running headless (no GUI)?

What snags are to be expected (e.g. what happens when I accidentally *do* have some X program running by accident, or anything else that may bug after the removal of consolekit)

Comment: Presumably you tried it? Results?

Comment: I have not, sorry.. in hindsight I could have safely (in the mean time I have decommissioned that specific Pi) but did not. Still interested in an answer though (for learning purposes).

Comment: I removed it, haven't noticed any consequences after 2 weeks; Kubuntu 17.04.